# Custom button remove focus on click but not on Enter keypress

Tags: javascript

Whats the best approach to remove focus from a button on mouse click but not when the `Enter` key is pressed using Javascript? I am using the `blur()` method on the `click` event but that doesn't work.

Please note that I cannot use `outline: none` or `outline: 0` for accessibility reasons. For more info refer to: http://www.outlinenone.com/

```js
var button = document.getElementById("btn");
button.addEventListener("click", removeFocus);

function removeFocus(event) {
 event.target.blur();
}
```

```css
button {
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  height: 36px;
  line-height:36px;
  padding: 0 12px;
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">
  Hello
</button>
```

Comment: outline is what causes this, if you can't remove them, I don't think there is another way

Comment: i dont think thats accurate. stackoverflow website itself does this. try clicking on the any of the items on the header of stackoverflow and you wont see any outline styles and try using a keyboard to navigate and click and you will see one.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript solution

```js
var button = document.getElementById("btn");
button.addEventListener("click", clickEvent);
button.addEventListener("keypress", clickEvent);
function clickEvent(event){
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
  } else {
    button.blur();
  }
}
```

```css
button {
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  height: 36px;
  line-height:36px;
  padding: 0 12px;
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">
  Hello
</button>
```